# Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: in Protractor IE11 execution

Tags: angularjs, node.js, automation, jasmine, protractor

I am getting error in IE11 as

> Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "root element (body) has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app.

when I execute my protractor scripts.I set **framework: jasmine2** but it didn't help out.However same working fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Following is my code:

```
// The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  //config.seleniumAddress = 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub';
  maxSessions: 1,

 capabilities: 
  {
  'browserName': 'internet explorer'
  },
      framework: 'jasmine',
              specs: ['TC_Sprint2_Case1.js'],

onPrepare: function() {   
      beforeEach(function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
    });  

      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
         baseDirectory: 'D:/Manoj/TestReport3/',

         docTitle: 'Test Case Execution Details',
         docName: 'BYTestReport.html',
//Meta builder      
  metaDataBuilder: function(spec, descriptions, results, capabilities){
            var metaData = {
                description: descriptions.join('|'),
                 passed: results.passed(),
                 os: 'Windows 7',               
                 browser: {
                  name: capabilities.caps_.browserName
                  , version: capabilities.caps_.version
                }
              };
            if(results.items_.length > 0) {
              var result = results.items_[0];
             metaData.message = result.message;                    
               metaData.trace = result.trace.stack;                         
            }           
return metaData;
}  // Meta Builder ends 
}));
   },
```

Comment: Are you testing on an angular page or a non-angular page?

Comment: @GirishSortur I am testing on angular page.But when we execute in Internet Explorer first it will launch "http://localhost:28813/" then it will navigate to my angular page.So problem here is protractor started its execution on non-angular page itself,it is not waiting till reach the angular page.

Comment: Can you try to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false` if its an angular page in your conf.js `onPrepare()` function or in your `beforeAll()` function and see if it works ? Also if you are getting error at any particular element, then wait until angular is loaded using `browser.waitForAngular().then(function(){//Check for element});`

Comment: I tried as _onPrepare: function() { 
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
}_ and _beforeEach(function() {
   
   browser.get('https://login.newrelic.com/');
   browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
  });_ But both the case I m getting error as "     Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "root element (body) has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use    `browser.driver.get('https://google.co.in');` instead of `browser.get('https://google.co.in');`

Earlier I used `browser.get(URL)`. It caused the synchronization problem.When I use `browser.driver.get(URL)`.It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your config, try setting nativeEvents to false:

```
capabilities:{
    browserName: 'internet explorer'
    nativeEvents:false
},
```

IE sometimes hangs on startup and this seems to solve it for me. This being said, there are other things that could cause IE to not bind.

Comment: What tag do you have your ng-app on?

Comment: **html class="no-js ng-scope" ng-app="busApp"** -This is the tag used in application

Comment: Sounds like you need to try browser.waitForAngular if you haven't already.

Comment: Tried as follow.But error exists. ** it('Testcase-TC_BY_08-question_Alternate flow', function() {
    
    browser.waitForAngular();
    page_validation();
 Login();
    Questionpage_validation();

}); **

Comment: I believe the proper format is: browser.waitForAngular().then(function(){page_validation(); Login(); Questionpage_validation();}); You have to remember that most things in Protractor return promises that must be handled correctly.